# Let me know solution because something wrong in my codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT `cat_name` FROM (`cat_manager`) WHERE `parent_id` = Array
```

Comment: Looks like your building your SQL query by concatenation, and the parent_id is supposed to be compared to a number, but you are building your query to compare it to a PHP array. Can you please share the PHP code?

Comment: I agree with Jason W. You probably want something like 

"(...) WHERE parent_id IN(".implode(',', $array).")";

Comment: We kinda need to see your model, otherwise we’re all just guessing.

Comment: Thanks :) I have done it, I was " passing array of ids " a little mistake i had done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter then why don't you use codiegniter active record library to make the SQL queries writing them as plain SQL.

```
$select = $this->db->select('cat_name')
               ->from('cat_manager')
               ->where_in('parent_id', $yourArray);

$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function function_name()
    {
        $data = $_POST['input field name'];//align variable to data

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT cat_name FROM cat_manager WHERE parent_id='$data'");//retrieve single item which  is equal to $data
        $result = $query->result_array();//asign it has objective array
        return $result;//return array
    }
```